# Why define a macro with the same name and content in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am looking into `if_link.h` in the Linux kernel headers and it contains this enum:

```
enum {
        IFLA_UNSPEC,
        IFLA_ADDRESS,
        IFLA_BROADCAST,
        IFLA_IFNAME,
        IFLA_MTU,
        IFLA_LINK,
        IFLA_QDISC,
        IFLA_STATS,
        IFLA_COST,
#define IFLA_COST IFLA_COST
        IFLA_PRIORITY,
#define IFLA_PRIORITY IFLA_PRIORITY
        IFLA_MASTER,
#define IFLA_MASTER IFLA_MASTER
....
}
```

The defines look useless; what is their purpose? And why do only some of the items have defines?

Comment: Maybe the code uses `#ifdef IFLA_COST` somewhere

Comment: What is really puzzling is, Why to define the macros there. Because indeed, perhaps there is a use for them elsewhere that expect them to be macros.

Comment: Maybe there used to be a `define` which was changed to an enum, and this is just for backward compatibility. Did you try `git blame`?

Comment: My guess is those enum valurs were added later so the defines are so code can use an ifdef to see if they are present.

Comment: @JohnHascall - could be but then an empty macro is sufficient - like `#define IFLA_COST`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8588649/124319

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688702/defines-inside-enum

Comment: @ZabojCampula if the macro was empty, you'd be screwed if you wanted to use the enum value as an enum value `if (blah == IFLA_COST) ...` would end up as `if (blah == ) ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean by "#define X X"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355395/what-does-it-mean-by-define-x-x)

Comment: @PiRocks The answer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355395/what-does-it-mean-by-define-x-x" does contain a generic answer to my question. But the accepted answer from coredump is better from my point of view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Matthew Slattery [mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588649/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-these-define-within-an-enum#comment10661711_8588681), the GCC manual has a section, namely [§3.10.5 Self-Referential Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/cpp/Self_002dReferential-Macros.html#Self_002dReferential-Macros), which describes the possible uses of such macros.

One possible use is to avoid infinite expansion when a macro expands into a call to itself, but this is a discouraged practice. The other use is to define both preprocessor macros and enums:

> You might do this if you want to define numeric constants with an enum, but have `#ifdef' be true for each constant.

So this is basically what [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315475/why-define-a-macro-with-the-same-name-and-content-in-c#comment71784657_42315475) said in the above comment.

This seems to be confirmed by [this patch](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2012-December/msg01319.html):

> > <rant> Why do the kernel developers behave so inconsistently? I much
> >     prefer interfaces where an enum value is ALSO added as a define to
> >     itself, to make it easy to probe which features are available in the
> >     current set of headers.
>
> The really frustrating part is the *some of* the enum values in this
>   set have #defines, and some of them don't.

Answer (score 1):

This macros used in **IPv4 protocol** for provides the ability to create, remove, or get information about a specific network interface.  See [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html).

Comment: This does not really explain why there is a mix of macros and enums. I did not find anything about this in the link, but maybe I missed it. Can you quote the relevant part of the man page?